# ios UITextView in UIAlertcontroller show keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextview, uialertcontroller

I already set textView in UIAlertController like the sample code:

```
-(void) addMessage:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"New message" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 250, 30)];
label.text = @"Demo alert!!";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[viewController.view addSubview:label];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 250, 60)];
[viewController.view addSubview:textView];

[alertController setValue:viewController forKey:@"contentViewController"];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];
[alertController addAction:ok];
[alertController addAction:cancel];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:nil];

});
```

}

So,I want show keyboard when alertController present.What can I do?

Comment: Call "becomeFirstResponder" for the UILabel once the UIAlertController presentation completion handler is called.

Comment: it worked!!  Sean,thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use textView in AlertController?
It should be UITextField.
You can use method addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler to add a textField to AlertController

In Swift like that:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (nameTextField) in
        nameTextField.placeholder = "Enter Channel Name here ..."
        nameTextField.text = "name"
        nameTextField.tag = 1
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.textDidChange), name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: nameTextField)
        nameTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    }
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    }
```